# Relationship between dual space and adjoint of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of adjoint of a linear operator. Given a finite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ over a field $F$, I know the dual space is the vector space $H^*$ of all linear forms $f:H\rightarrow F$.

Is the adjoint of a linear map $A$ on $H$ a member of $H^*$? Or what is the relationship between a linear map $f:H\rightarrow K$ and the dual space, generally? What confuses me even more is  this special case: take the bra-ket notation. It says that for any ket $|\psi\rangle\in H$ there is a linear form from $H^*$ called a bra ($|\psi\rangle:=\langle\psi,-\rangle$-also weird, is $\psi$ a function or not?...), such that bra is the adjoint of ket.

It's a bit of a mess, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58146/transpose-of-a-linear-mapping

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, there's something called the Riesz Representation Theorem. To understand it, start by fixing a vector $v \in H$. We can now use the dot product to define a continuous linear functional $L_v: H \rightarrow F$ by $$L_v(w) = \langle w,v \rangle.$$ What the Riesz Representation Theorem says is that *every* continuous linear functional $\phi:H \rightarrow F$ arises in this way! That is, given any element $\phi$ of the dual space $H^\ast$, there is some $v \in H$ so that $\phi(w) = \langle w, v \rangle$. So this is why we can sort of think as linear functionals as elements of the Hilbert space, and vice versa. In more mathematical terms, we say that the dual of $H$ is isomorphic to $H$.

Second, a note on dual spaces: I believe that typically the space $H^\ast$ is defined to be the set of *continuous* linear functionals. This distinction is important, as there are different types of duals. So far, I've been talking about the topological dual. However, there is an algebraic dual, which I have seen denoted $H^\star$, which is just all linear functionals $H \rightarrow F$, no continuity assumed. The Reisz Representation Theorem concerns only the topological dual. (The duals are actually the same for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, but I don't believe the Hilbert spaces encountered in QM are.)

Third, adjoints: Given any Hilbert spaces $H, K$, and a continuous linear functional $A: H \rightarrow K$, there is a continuous linear map called the adjoint $A^\ast:K \rightarrow H$ (note that it goes the other way) that is defined by the equation $\langle Av, w \rangle = \langle v, A^\ast w \rangle$. You typically only see the case $K = H$. So no, the adjoint of an operator $A: H \rightarrow H$ is not an element of $H^\ast$, since the members of $H^\ast$ are continuous linear functionals from $H$ into $F$, and $H^\ast$ goes from $H$ into $H$.

Unfortunately, I don't know much about QM, so this last bit is just speculating on how I think the notation works. If you consider kets $|\phi \rangle \in H$ to be an element of the Hilbert space, then there is a continuous linear functional that I suppose you could call $\langle \phi |$ defined by $\langle \phi | v \rangle = \langle v, \phi \rangle.$ And conversely, given a bra $\langle \phi |$, by the Reisz Representation Theorem, there is a bra $| \phi \rangle$ so that $\langle \phi | v \rangle = \langle \phi , v \rangle.$

Comment: You say $A: H \to K$ is a continuous linear functional. But don't you mean $A$ is a continuous linear operator? If it was a continuous linear functional it would be defined as $A: H \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$). Also you say members of $H^\ast$ are continuous linear functionals $H^\ast: H \to F$ but contradict it in the next part by saying $H^\ast: H \to H$. Or have I misinterpreted you?

Comment: yes, I think that he meant an operator cause, as you said, a functional assumes values in a field.