# Dual operator relationship with complex conjugate.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $n$ dimensional vector space spanned by $\{e_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$.

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator with matrix transformation $A$.  Is there any relationship between the dual operator $T^{*}:V^{*}\to V^{*}$, and the complex conjugate $A^{*}$ of $A$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58146/transpose-of-a-linear-mapping

Comment: So in part (2) where they explain it, is it just the regular transpose that corresponds to $T^{*}$, not the complex conjugate?

Comment: I've heard of "dual space" and "dual basis" but not "dual operator". Is there any link to it or short explanation?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Usually we define it as $(T^*f)(v)=fTv$.

Comment: @lovinglifein2012: Yes. The difference originates from the fact that the inner product has conjugate symmetry and Riesz representation theorem gives us an anti-isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

See Stone and Goldbart, Mathematics for Physics, page 753 for a brief explanation. The dual operator is linear, so it does not have a simple relationship to the complex conjugate of an operator.